# Can I boot into other OS (such as Ubuntu) from an Android OS tablet that have a USB host?

Tags: usb, boot, usb-on-the-go

I have the following scenario:

A user have a Android OS tablet that have Android 4.0

The tablet have a full USB port (not the mini USB port)

The user have a thumbdrive that have a `boot from USB` version Ubuntu.

Is it possible and how do the user goes about booting the USB Ubuntu on an Android OS tablet?

This also apply to any `boot from USB` version OS.

Comment: Two questions: *What tablet?* and *Can the tablet boot from a thumbdrive?*

Comment: @t0mm13b The tablet is this http://store.archos.com/carbon-android-tablet-p-5031.html. But I would like to know how can I know that if that tablet can boot from a thumbdrive? (is it that I have to use some Apps that will tell me that this particular tablet can boot from a thumbdrive or ???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: *No*.
Longer answer: The thumb-drive version of Ubuntu is for x86 processors. There are ways to run Ubuntu in Android, all of them requiring a Ubuntu port with an ARM architecture. Search for *Complete Linux Installer* in the Play Store for basic stuff. It will rum on top of Android in a virtualized environment, and you can connect to its environment and everything. Just download the image and put it on your flash drive instead.

Comment: What if you have an android tablet with an intel CPU? I have an iView i700  with an Intel Dual Core CloverTrail+Z2520 processor. Which near as I can tell is a 32-bit x86 CPU. I'm frustrated by my inability to move apps to the sdcard (I'm beginning to hate KitKat)